# Datascientistworkbench R Parallel clusterEvalQ() -

Tags: r, parallel-processing, stanford-nlp

I would be happy to get some help. 
Usually preparing a cluster works fine on my local machine (Windows), when calling clusterEvalQ to initialize the packages for all cores. 
However, doing the same thing in the environment of the datascientistworkbench (https://my.datascientistworkbench.com) results in the following error message:

```
> clusterEvalQ(cl, expr = {
+     library(coreNLP)
+   }) #init coreNLP for all cores
```

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  15 nodes produced errors; first error: package or namespace load failed for ‘coreNLP’
```

Without cluster, the coreNLP package works regularly.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no solution for this problem, since mclapply did not work as well due to the current resource limitations of the datascientistworkbench. I can just recommend the following tutorial, for setting up an AWS EC2 cluster with RStudio accessible through any browser with scalable ressources: http://strimas.com/r/rstudio-cloud-1/